# Change div value on input value change. Multiple changes on the same page

Tags: jquery

I have multiple INPUTs with a save button each that should update other DIVs that contain the same ID in the id attribute. For the moment I can only change the value when I give the exact id with Jquery.

How can I change only the value that is on the same clicked parent div?

HTML

```
    <div>
  <input type="text" id="newbud-2508891" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0">
  <a id="newbudbtn-2508891" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;" onClick="showMessage()">SAVE</a>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508891" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);">$10.00</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="newbud-2508892" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0">
  <a id="newbudbtn-2508892" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;" onClick="showMessage()">SAVE</a>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508892" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);">$10.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
function showMessage() {
    var message = jQuery("#newbud-2508891").val();
    jQuery("#bud-2508891").text(message);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t8wpsubg/)

EDIT: How to have the same behavior for both parent DIV with the same JQuery code. For the moment I have to give the exact ID of the input and the result DIV in the code. Is there a way to have a code that doesn't require IDs and change both results DIV when the corresponding input is changed?

Comment: It's not immediately clear what your intended scenario is. Can you add some details to this to explain what you expect to happen? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So if what I'm hearing you is correct, you want a helper function that changes the value of the input that is associated with the button that's clicked, correct? So you're looking for `this` element to be specified?

Comment: Exactly! But I'm not that knowledgeable when it's JQuery stuff.

Comment: Ok - So to clarify: You have a button that's updating *multiple* values? Or is one input linked to a single button? You can either tie them by class, or by id. class enables you do do .querySelectorAll("class") to get all of the things that match what you're looking for, and then `forEach()` over each of those elements.

Comment: It's one input linked to a single button that updates a single div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you do not need to use the `onClick` attribute on html tags. Further you can use selectors like `[attribute^=value]` [to get elements which attributes begins with the given values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp).
Try something like this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('*[id^="newbudbtn-"]').on('click', showMessage);

  function showMessage(event) {
    var elem = $(event.target);
    var id = elem.attr('id').replace('newbudbtn-', '');

    var source = $('#newbud-' + id)
    var target = $('#bud-' + id);

    if (source.length && target.length) {
      target.text('$' + source.val());
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="newbud-2508891" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0">
  <a id="newbudbtn-2508891" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;">SAVE</a>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508891" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="newbud-2508892" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0">
  <a id="newbudbtn-2508892" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;">SAVE</a>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508892" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your code doesn't seem to be working, Value doesn't change when the input value changes and the save button is clicked.

Comment: If I click on the save button the value of the input will be displayed in your "dropdown" -> "bud". If you change the value and click the save button again, it will still work. Do I misunderstood something?

Comment: Furthermore, you can use onClick events in HTML and pass `this` to access *where* click came from e.g. `onClick="myfunc(this)"`

Comment: I'm sorry but the code still doesn't work on my end, I changed the input value and clicked save and nothing happened. I will try your onClick="myfunc(this). This seems like a promising solution. Thank you

Comment: @CreekBarbara Do you run the snippet on my answer here on stackoverflow for testing?

Comment: I've tested the code on JSFIDDLER too with the same result.

Comment: @CreekBarbara I modified my answer a few seconds after posting. You don't get the latest Version - please try the current code. Additionally you do not need to insert the script tag in html while using jquery in the javascript window of jsfiddle :)

Comment: I'm happy that i could help you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better served by using classes and then querying based on hierarchy.

Here is my example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/sepyd0fq/20/)

```js
function showMessage(e) {
 // We get the parent of the button that clicked it
 var node = e.parentNode;
  
  // Get initial value from sibling input
  var initialValue = node.querySelector("INPUT").value;
  
  
 // We query each of the elements in that container
  var elements = node.querySelectorAll(".text-change");
 elements.forEach( el =>
  {
   el.innerHTML = initialValue; 
  });
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0 text-change">
  <button id="newbudbtn-2508891" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;" onClick="showMessage(this)">SAVE</button>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508891" class="text-change" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);">$10.00</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="newbud-2508892" value="10.00" required="" class="form-control border-0 text-change">
  <button id="newbudbtn-2508892" class="btn btn-sm text-info bgbtb" style="color: white !important; background-color: #007bff;" onClick="showMessage(this)">SAVE</button>
  <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="bud-2508892" class="text-change style="border-bottom: 2px solid #bdbdbd;display: inline-block;color: rgb(189, 189, 189);">$10.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the event (target is the div you clicked on)

```
function showMessage(event)
{
    console.log(event.target)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was asking for. Thank you though.